# Is it true to write $|\sum_{i=1}^N q_i x_i|\leq \sup_i|x_i|$?

Tags: summation, absolute-value, supremum-and-infimum

My intuition tells me that the following equation is true but I can't prove it:

$$|\sum_{i=1}^N q_i x_i|\leq \sup_i|x_i|$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|x|$ is x's absolute value, $\sum_{i=1}^N q_i=1$ and $q_i \geq 0$.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: [Kavi Rama Murthy] It's really a big problem in my research paper. So, I need to program it, since, $q_i$ are unknown, so, I need to prove this for use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $s= \sup_j|x_j|$. Then

$|\sum_{i=1}^N q_i x_i| \le \sum_{i=1}^N q_i |x_i|  \le \sum_{i=1}^N q_i s=s\sum_{i=1}^N q_i =s$.